# Retrieving values from HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap, iterator

I have my HashMap as below:

```
Map<String, List<Double>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Double>>();//map
Iterator<java.util.Map.Entry<String, List<Double>>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
List<Double> times = new ArrayList<Double>();//arraylist
```

There is a String as a key and two double values. What I want to do is when I call the key I want to assign those two double values individually into two double variables.

Comment: *I expect some code examples.* What is this, a test?

Comment: Actually the whole code is so big, that is why i didn't copy the whole thing....

Comment: What are you stuck on? Do you know how to get a value from a map? Do you know how to get a value from a list? Both are extremely basic tasks and can easily be answered with a quick search.

Comment: Yeah ! I got it now ! Thanks.

Comment: I expect you to stop being demanding, since you're asking for free help.  When people say "I expect" something from other people,  it usually sounds like a demand. Like a boss ordering someone to do something. That may not be what you thought you're saying but that's how people tend to regard it.

Comment: I am so sorry about that. I really didn't mean to order or be like a boss. I am not English and I may don't get the idea of the word as others get it. I apologize for the inconvenience. Really sorry about that. I will remove that part from the question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any error checking (such as missing keys or malshaped List):

```
List<Double> times = map.get("theKey");
if(times.size() > 1){//To avoid the java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    double t1 = times.get(0);
    double t2 = times.get(1);
}
```